# Quasar Dev Stuck Without Errors

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

When I ran "quasar dev"  CLI always build at 49% of without errors. Then I ran "quasar clean" after that I ran "quasar dev" again but same problem.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmMHN.png)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have an error in your code and it cannot process it.
To detect the error, try

```
quasar build
```

and you will see that it will show you an error;)